# testing mysql injection, query dont discard with --?

Tags: php, sql

Im testing my query on mysql injections, but when i use -- it doesnt discard. anybody know whats the problem?

Comment: Hard to say.. do you want us to guess or give you an accurate answer based on **MORE** information that you would provide?

Comment: Post the query and code in question. Otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: He had an hour to update his question so I am for closing this topic!

Answer (score 1):

[Comment Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html):

MySQL Server supports three comment styles:

- From a `#` character to the end of the line.
- From a `--` sequence to the end of the line.
- From a `/*` sequence to the following `*/` sequence, as in the C programming language.

So if you want to disable a part of your query for testing purposes, either use `#` or `--` if it's a single line, or use `/*` and `*/` to disable multiple lines.

More info on injection: http://www.google.com/#q=sql+injection.